# Issue with Mockito Inline

Tags: java, maven, junit, mockito

So I am trying to mock a static method in Java 11 with Junit5 tests and Mockito. Previously I was doing this using PowerMockito, but this isnt supported with Junit5. I am trying to use the built in inline mock functionality in Mockito-Inline, but when I add the dependency to the pom, maven is able to resolve the dependency but no class files are built.

What I mean is that if I go do the dependencies in IntelliJ, the dependency folder for mockito-inline does appear but no class files or org.mockito-inline folder is there.

Has anyone experienced anything like this or know how I could potentially resolve? I have tried so many different versions of mockito dependencies, cleared my intellij cache many times. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: At least show your pom; details matter. Also, do you expect maven to build .class files for a dependency? That's not how maven works...

Comment: The mockito-inline contains only a two files for configuration internally. No class file. Apart from that in general I would say using powermockito (or the need for that) sounds like a smell for me...Furthermore I would suggest to check the docs: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#48